# Is there a work around for this error...The method synchronizedSet(Set<T>, Object) from the type Collections is not visible

Tags: java, set, hashtable

I am implementing the Hashtable functionality which I found on 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java.

I have literally typed the entire source word for word. However, Eclipse is giving me three errors:

1. `The method synchronizedSet(Set<T>, Object) from the type Collections is not visible`
2. `The method synchronizedCollection(Collection<T>, Object) from the type Collections is not visible`
3. `A duplicate error when calling synchronizedSet() again`

Here is the code in which the errors are located:

```
public Set<K> keySet(){
    if (keySet == null)
        keySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new KeySet(), this);
    return keySet;
}

private class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    public Iterator<K> iterator(){
        return getIterator(KEYS);
    }
    public int size(){
        return count;
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o){
        return containsKey(o);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o){
        return HashTable.this.remove(o) != null;
    }
    public void clear(){
        HashTable.this.clear();
    }
}

public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet(){
    if (entrySet == null)
        entrySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new EntrySet(), this);
    return entrySet;
}

private class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator(){
        return getIterator(ENTRIES);
    }

    public boolean add(Map.Entry<K,V> o) {
        return super.add(o);
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o){
        if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
            return false;
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)o;
        Object key = entry.getKey();
        Entry[] tab = table;
        int hash = key.hashCode();
        int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFF) % tab.length;

        for (Entry e = tab[index]; e != null; e = e.next)
            if (e.hash == hash && e.equals(entry))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o){
        if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
            return false;
        Map.Entry<K,V> entry = (Map.Entry<K,V>) o;
        K key = entry.getKey();
        Entry[] tab = table;
        int hash = key.hashCode();
        int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFF) % tab.length;

        for (Entry<K, V> e = tab[index], prev = null; e != null; prev = e, e = e.next){
            if (e.hash == hash && e.equals(entry)){
                modCount++;
                if (prev != null)
                    prev.next = e.next;
                else
                    tab[index] = e.next;
                count--;
                e.value = null;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int size(){
        return count;
    }
    public void clear(){
        HashTable.this.clear();
    }
}

public Collection<V> values(){
    if (values == null)
        values = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ValueCollection(), this);
    return values;
}
```

I have looked into the `Collections` source as well as the `Set` source code and, for the life of me, find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-parameter versions of `synchronizedCollection` and `synchronizedSet` are package-private methods that can only be accessed from classes in the `java.util` package.  The `grepcode.com` source you've linked to is the source of `Hashtable`, which is part of the `java.util` package, and can therefore use these methods.  But you can't.

The only thing I can suggest is to look at the `Collections` source to see how they're implemented, and try to do something similar.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Very helpful !

Comment: I think you can invoke them with reflection if you really want.